# Different versions of ntp used by apt-get install

Tags: apt, scripts, ntp

I've set up a microsoft azure's arm template that creates virtual machine on Ubuntu 16.04-LTS and then runs a shell script to install additional packages, in particular `ntp`.

One of my users complained that the script failed. This seems to be what caused the problem:

```
sudo apt-get -y install ntp
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/ntp/ntp_4.2.8p4+dfsg-3ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
```

This link is indeed 404 now, which is strange.

Then I used the same script myself and it worked out alright, however this is the version of ntp I ended up with (from apt logs):

```
ntp:amd64 (1:4.2.8p4+dfsg-3ubuntu5.5), libopts25:amd64 (1:5.18.7-3, automatic)

Preparing to unpack .../ntp_1%3a4.2.8p4+dfsg-3ubuntu5.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ntp (1:4.2.8p4+dfsg-3ubuntu5.5) ...
```

so the difference is in version number: `5.5` vs `5.3`.

The first line in the script is `sudo apt update`, so it seems that `apt` should have used the latest version in both cases (?).

Could it be that `5.3` was somehow posted by mistake and then removed? Otherwise, how is it possible that two different versions are requested by the same version of OS?

Comment: It might be that your user that complained started from a not up to date system, and therefore requested an obsolete version on ntp.

Comment: Hi @DougSmythies ! Could you give more details: which part of the system might have been not up to date? The VM is created by azure and the script is run right after that. I use `sudo apt update` as the first command. What else should be updated?

Comment: `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade` should have been good enough.